# About System.currentTimeMillis() and Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()

Tags: java, calendar, milliseconds

Why are System.currentTimeMillis() and Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() different?

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){


        long t2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(t1);
        System.out.println(t2);
     }
}
```

The output is:

```
1491925013006                                                                                                                                                     
1491925012998
```

Comment: it is different because you are calling one after another

Comment: They look to be equivalent from their Javadoc.

Comment: They are different because time has moved on between calling one and then calling another.  Unless you're running it in a stasis field.

Comment: Because 8 milliseconds has elapsed between the call to `getInstance()` and the call to `currentTimeMillis()`. The 8 milliseconds may be inaccurate, depending on the precision (ticks) of the underlying clock.

Answer (score 1):

They are different because time has passed between when you called one vs when you called the other.  Even if you call System.currentTimeMillis() over and over again, it will keep giving you different responses.